# Is tearDown() supposed to run after each test?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, robotium

I thought the `tearDown()` is supposed to run after each test, but what I see from logs is that it is started just after `setUp()` method. Can you guys clarify?

```
public class LaunchManagerActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<LaunchManagerActivity> {
    private Solo solo;

    public LaunchManagerActivityTest() {
        super(LaunchManagerActivity.class);

    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        Log.e("Dev", "setup");

        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());

    }

    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
        Log.e("Dev", "tearDown  ");

    }
```

Output:

```
02-11 11:33:33.095: E/Dev(26779): setup
02-11 11:33:34.395: E/Dev(26779): tearDown
```

Comment: You don't have a testcase. So, this is expected, I believe.

Comment: Yes, it is called after each testXXX method.  Probably your test just does not output anything.

Comment: @RKajaMohideen I think he does have at least one test case hidden in superclass.  Otherwise, neither `setUp` nor `tearDown` would be called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have no tests in the class you posted so it just ran setup and then teardown. That is the expected behaviour, if you had any test it would run:

```
constructor()
setUp();
testXXX();
tearDown();
```

if you had two tests it would run

```
constructor()
setUp();
testXXX();
tearDown();

setUp();
testXXX2();
tearDown();
```

Remember a test in junit 3 (which android uses) has to start with the word test and be in the same class.

to test what i said add the following methods in:

```
public void testXXX(){
    Log.d("Dev", "testXXX  ");
}

public void testXXX2(){
    Log.d("Dev", "testXXX2  ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is JUnit3. The tearDown runs after each test. Do you have any test in your test file? JUnit will run only tests defined in the current class..